# SQL table access: Many accessing one or one accessing many better?

Tags: sql

I am making some SQL tables for books for a digital library. I have a table "book", which stores mostly static information about each book.

My other table is "ownedBook" which stores data about the books in relation to the users that own them in their own collection.

As users read the books, I want to frequently update the database with how much time they have spent looking at each book (in seconds). The question:

Is it more efficient for my sql database to have many users adding their time to the one table's "book" column or should I be recording that time in the "ownedBook" table?

Considering both options: If saved in the "book" table, one row in "book" would be getting updated very frequently with different users adding time(seconds they've spent on a certain book) to one column. That might be bad, but on the other time it would be easy to look up how much time people had spent looking at that book.

On the other hand, if recording this time in the "ownedBook" table, only one row in that would be getting updated at a time and much less frequently, but the task of finding out how much time readers have spent looking at each book would then involve getting all the "ownedBooks" and adding up the time users had accrued in each one.

Any help appreciated!
-Not Aliens

Comment: Can you clarify "frequently"?

Comment: Haven't gotten that far yet, plan is to find a way to save the time spent on a book as frequently as possible while they are online reading it - as I don't know how to send that data upon the user's session expiring- or something like that

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I don't understand what "add time" is supposed to be doing.

Comment: alright done. Thanks

Comment: I would go with the second option of updating the `ownedBooks`. Proper indexing and, perhaps, a materialized view (if such a concept is supported in your RDBMS) would help with speedy lookups. Furthermore you can tell each user how much time they've spent reading books, or a specific genre, where if you store on `books` you lose that ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only store the total time per book, you lose the information of time spent per book per user. I assume you don't want to lose this information. Going with that assumption, you want to store total time per user per book (in the ownedBook table). I assume you will also want to query the total time per book frequently, so to avoid performance issues, you may want to [denormalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) the data by also storing the total time per book (in the book table).

Since you are designing this to support high-frequency updates, I suggest having a third table as a queue. Let's call it bookReading. Instead of updating the other tables directly, you would insert a new row into this table for each update coming from a user (i.e. user id, book id, read_started_timestamp, read_ended_timestamp). This should support a high frequency of inserts (don't set up foreign keys for even faster performance). You can then set up a scheduled recurring task (e.g. every five seconds) which processes all accumulated reads in one go: updates the total times in book and ownedBook tables, and removes the processed reads from bookReading.

This should allow you to have good performance on writes as well as on reads (queries).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the 2 table options. 
1 table for the books, 1 table for who has read and for how long.
Also you need 1 field in each table that is the same, that link the 2 tables together.
It would be a unique field in the books table, perhaps the ISBN number, if you don't have them you can have SQL create a uniqueidentifier for you using newid(). You don't have to show anyone this field.
This helps keeps your data consistent.